# Systemd Service only works when restarted

Tags: systemd-unit

I have a systemd service which runs a python script. The script opens a webpage, and then runs a http socket server to receive commands.

When I reboot my raspberry pi (model 3 b v1.2) the service status is active and running. The webpage opens, but the server doesn't start.

If I restart the service, the script runs and works, including the server.

The service code looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=My magic display service.
After=graphical.target
Requires=network.target

[Service]
Type=idle
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"
User=pi
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/DisplayAndControl.py
Restart=always
StandardOutput=file:/tmp/DisplayAndControl.log
StandardError=inherit

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried adding a 30 second wait at the start of the python code and this works including the server.

How do I find out what dependency the script requires and isn't currently getting on boot, but loads at some point before 30 seconds? And if I then put After=name_of_dependency.target should that work?

Thanks,

Comment: Why you do not use the classic "xinit" way (or your desktop environment configuration file). You tell your graphical environment to start your program. We all do this (e.g. for docking, clocks, and many other services).

Comment: You can use what Giacomo said as well as using systemd-generator (but I'm not sure if that will work). Try using in your service: `After=network.target graphical.target` or `After=network-online.target graphical.target` and remove `Requires=network.target`. Also you can change `WantedBy=multi-user.target` to `WantedBy=graphical.target`